# How can I count the number of times an element occurs in a specific position in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, bigdata

I have a large number of arrays of zeros and ones, like so - 
Array length for each array is 812.

```
    a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0,....]
    b = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1,....]
    .
    .
    .
    x = [0, 1, 0,..........]
```

What I would like to do is count the number of times 1 and 0 appear at the first, second,...812th position. Any thoughts or ideas are appreciated.
What I would like is an array like:
`array = [(32,56), (78,89)....]` where the tuple's first element gives number of 1s at the first position(index) and second element, the number of 0s. The arrays are used to store 812 features for Naive Bayes classifier implementation.

Comment: If you organized your arrays (lists?) into a 2D numpy array, say, `xy`, the solution would be as simple as `xy.sum(axis=0)`.

Comment: Would sum give me number of zeros and ones? At each position?

Comment: The sum of 0's and 1's is by definition the number of 1's.

Comment: How are the arrays stored?

Comment: Arrays are stored as lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sum idea would work too but I had the idea of transposing the list then running collections.Counter for each row

```
import numpy as np
import collections

nums = [
    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
]

np_nums = np.array(nums)
transposed = np.transpose(np_nums)
for i, row in enumerate(transposed):
    print("Index {} {}".format(i, dict(collections.Counter(row))))
```

This outputs:

```
Index 0 {1: 1, 0: 2}
Index 1 {0: 1, 1: 2}
Index 2 {0: 3}
Index 3 {1: 2, 0: 1}
Index 4 {0: 1, 1: 2}
```

Which means that at index 0 there is one one and two zeroes, at index 1 there is one zero and two ones

Answer (score -1):

This is what I understood based on your question

```
def arrayCount(arrays, index):
    data = {}
    for x in arrays:
        if data.get(x[index]) is None:
            data[x[index]] = 1
        else:
            data[x[index]] += 1
    return data


a = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
b = [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
x = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
y = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
z = [0, 2, 0, 1, 1]

arrays = [a, b, x, y, z]
print arrayCount(arrays, 1)

'''OUTPUT'''
# {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 1}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here I am providing a general solution(u can use it for any value in an array including 0 and 1). combine all your list to numpy nd-array, as all list have same length

```
import numpy as np
concat_array = np.concatenate((a,b,c,...x), axis=0)
```

Find number of occurrence of a value along axis=0(column wise) and combine to form a tuple

```
# use loop if have more unique values
n_ones = (concat_array = 1).sum(axis=0)
n_zeros = (concat_array = 0).sum(axis=0)
#zip it to form a tuple
result = list(zip(n_ones, n_zeros))
```

print(result)

```
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 2), (0, 3)] #a dummy result
```